# Mongoid has_and_belongs_to_many, inverse_of: :nil, store_as

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

In my code I have a user class:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :person_record_bookmarks, inverse_of: nil, :class_name => "PersonRecord"
end
```

now it will generate person_record_bookmarks_ids in my document. This name is too long, is there any way to store it as shorter name in the database?  In embed documents we can use store_as:, but seems it doesn't work for references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

foreign_key is what you are looking for

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :person_record_bookmarks, inverse_of: nil, :class_name => "PersonRecord", foreign_key :shorter_name
end
```

then your user will be:

```
{...shorter_name:[ObjectId("..."),ObjectId("...")]...}
```

You can user user.shorter_name to retrieve the list of ids or user.person_record_bookmarks to retrieve all PersonRecordBookmarks.where({_id: {$in: shorter_name})